# C++ STL map::find() problems

Tags: c++, stl, maps, find, breadth-first-search

I'm writing a solution for a simple programming problem, but I can't get map::find() to work. I am using maps to mark visited vertices when using BFS. I know I could use some other data structure, such as a 2D bool array, but I'm just really eager to make it work with maps.
Here's my code: http://pastebin.com/mANej4vp

The problem is that visited[tempR] is always true, even though the tempR position hasn't been visited yet. And the visited.size() is 1, but it responds to both the visited[now] and visited[tempR] as true; while tempR is not equal to now.

Duom.in file should contain this: http://pastebin.com/L7qMG0bd

Do you have any idea why is this happening?

Comment: Please reduce the problem to an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) and post that directly in your question.  I don't want to have to swim through hundreds of lines of pastebin code to debug your program.

Comment: I haven't gone through the code..but remember that using `operator[]` on map is not equivalent to `find`. `operator[]` will insert the value into the map if it can't find it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `operator<` and  `operator==` are inconsistent

for two positions

```
pos p1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};
pos p2 = {1, 10, 20, 30};

bool b1 = !(p1 < p2) && !(p2 < p1);
bool b2 = p1 == p2;
```

`b1` is true, so `b2` must be true by definition, but it's not.

In other words, rewrite your `operator<` to do proper comparison, not just `Hx`

Answer (score 2):

I haven't debugged your code, and I don't understand it really, but the semantic of `bool operator<(const pos& a) const` seems reversed to me.

Consider that std::map uses just that member operator, that should return  `this->Hx < a.Hx`, at least if Hx stands for a positive coordinate. And it should be a *total* order, being 2D coordinates seems that you should use a combination of x & y anyway...